# Windows HPC - Azure

Tags: azure

We are trying to burst out some of our complex calculation on Azure platform, however we are working within enterprise perimeter and what we are seeing is our calls are getting blocked to ussouth2.management.core.windows.net.

I have uploaded jpg attachment that specifically describes where the error is happening. I ran tcp sniffer and found out that calls to ussouth2xxx gets blocked.

So what i need to know is how does HPC Cluster manager knows to connect to ussouth2xxx address.  Any help in this regard is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, US South 2 is the entry point for none region related API calls. For example, subscription and cert management are not tied to any region, those API calls will go to USSouth2.